# Numpy Index Iterator

Tags: python, numpy, iterator

I don't remember whether this is Python or numpy specific. I once found an index iterator that is not in the main introduction and however I try to look for it, I couldn't find it anymore. This is what it gave me:

```
>>> foo = ones((1,2,3))

>>> for i in foo.getThisMagicIteratorIndexThiny():
>>>     print i
(0,0,0)
(0,0,1)
(0,0,2)
(0,1,0)
```

And, `foo[i]` would return the corresponding value. Does anyone know which iterator I am talking about?

Comment: You can use `for idx in np.ndindex(foo.shape):`

Comment: Perfect. If you add an answer, we can close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per flebool's comment the solution is to use `for idx in np.ndindex(foo.shape):`